# run a command as different user with available sudo permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

I want to run the below command

```
echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

i cannot do it it like below beecause bash is the process that actually directs output to the root-owned brightness file.

```
sudo echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

so how would i run this command but i

- do not want to be prompted for root password
- do not want to login as root, execute command and exit
- should use available sudo permissions available for current user to execute command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking is impossible. Your current process is not being run by root, and only the root user can issue `setuid`. As such, another process has to be launched as the root user first (by using a setuid executable, in this case, `sudo`).

Here is the closest thing to what you're asking, with the impossible removed:

```
echo 1000 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

If you don't want this to prompt for a password, add a line in `/etc/sudoers` (by using `visudo`), like so (replace `rag` with your username):

```
Cmnd_Alias BACKLIGHT = /usr/bin/tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness, ! /usr/bin/tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness *
rag ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: BACKLIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

this works as well. I do not mind being prompted for my own password

`sudo bash -c "echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`.